# Error when trying to insert data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I keep getting a server error when trying to insert a simple query into my db. I've been looking it over for an hour and I can't find where the problem is.

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/frontpage/insert_into_db" method="POST">
    <input type = 'text' name='f1' id="searchbar" placeholder="Paste Terminal error here...">
    <input type= 'text' name='f2' id="searchbar" placeholder="Paste Terminal solution here...">
    <input type='submit' id="search" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

Model:

```
   function insert_into_db()
{
    $f1 = $_POST['f1'];
    $f2 = $_POST['f2'];
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `Errors` VALUES('$f1' , '$f2')");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function insert_into_db()
{
    $this->load->model('all');
    $this->all->insert_into_db();
    $this->load->view('success');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check logs and provide specific messages and can you also check if your table has more than two columns

Comment: If you could tell us *what* the server error is, that would be a huge help. Also, what the contents of `f1` and `f2` are, since if they contain any special SQL characters, all hell's going to break lose. You really, really want to use bound parameters (see Query Bindings at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: It doesn't say what the error is. It just shows this- http://d.pr/i/Xg1Z

Comment: Also, the contents of f1 and f2 don't contain any special SQL characters

Comment: http://d.pr/i/oQAU error message

Comment: how about table structure

Comment: Also, I have 3 columns in the table, but one of them is a auto increment id number

Comment: table structure http://d.pr/i/qCQP

Comment: Can you try to change the $f1 = $_POST['f1'] into $f1 =  $this->input->post('f1'); same with the f2.

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted it as a comment as it didn't seem to be the issue to the OP but it happened to be so I am making it a an answer.

```
function insert_into_db()
{
    $data = array('Error' => $this->input->post('f1'),
                  'Solution' => $this->input->post('f2')
                 );
    $this->db->insert('Errors', $data);
}
```

Mainly I am using the insert function and post methods directly from codeigniter instead of PHP's one.

Using the array I am defining the column names from your MySQL table and the data it's supposed to be used which will as well be properly escaped by codeigniter.